# netCDF4 and Basemap package on Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.7, importerror, matplotlib-basemap, keyerror, netcdf4

I hope someone can help me with this.

I am plotting netcdf data on a map using the mpl_toolkits.basemap and netCDF4.Dataset packages.
They worked perfectly a few month ago and I successfully plotted what I wanted. Now I want to update my work with newer data, but the same code doesn't work anymore.
I have reinstalled python several times, using several direcories (like conda_forge and anaconda) and different systems (pip, miniconda, anaconda) but nothing works for me, so I really do not know how to proceed.

I am currently using python 3.7 installed via miniconda on a Win10 machine and am using following packages in this particular code:

```
### IMPORT MODULES AND FUNCTIONS ##############################################
import os
import datetime             as dt
import numpy                as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot    as plt
from   netCDF4              import Dataset
from   mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
```

`from netCDF4 import Dataset` yields:

`ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

and `from   mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap` yields:

```
  File "C:\Users\drauter\Dropbox\OZONE\Extremes\geopotential_date_level_PLOT.py", line 32, in <module>
    from   mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

  File "C:\Users\drauter\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.py", line 155, in <module>

    pyproj_datadir = os.environ['PROJ_LIB']

  File "C:\Users\drauter\Miniconda3\lib\os.py", line 678, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None

KeyError: 'PROJ_LIB'
```

Proj is installed however.....

Has anybody experienced something similiar, or does anybody know what I could try?
I am also open for alternatives, although I don't really want to rewrite the entire code because of this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Double check that conda thinks `netCDF4` and `basemap` are installed with

```
conda list
```

You can also regardless try to re-install with:

```
conda install --force-reinstall netcdf4
conda install --force-reinstall basemap
```

From there, I wouldn't actually run the script, but just see if this works:

```
python -c 'from netCDF4 import Dataset'
python -c 'from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap'
```

Answer (score 0):

according to conda list both packages are installed (including proj4 which is necessary for basemap to work).

I did force reinstall them anyway, but

```
python -c 'from netCDF4 import Dataset'
python -c 'from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap'
```

unfurtunately doesn't work, it says:

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue with Basemap, it is a known problem for some versions:
https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/483

Even if PROJ4 is installed, Basemap still requires you to set the environment variable `PROJ_LIB`. But actually Basemap knows the location of PROJ4 since it imports `pyproj` successfully.

One possible solution is to replace yourself the problematic line in `mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.py`:

```py
pyproj_datadir = os.environ['PROJ_LIB']
```

with

```py
if 'PROJ_LIB' in os.environ:
    pyproj_datadir = os.environ['PROJ_LIB']
else:
    pyproj_datadir = pyproj.datadir.pyproj_datadir
```

assuming that your Basemap version imported the `pyproj` module before.